# Regex for checking existence of some special characters,a mandatory number and alphabets

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

My current Regex looks like

```
([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[\/\\#-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+
```

The regex should validate:

1. Alpha Numeric Charachters
2. Must Contain atleast One number
3. / , \ , # , - , are allowed
4. Must be less than 30 charachters

The regex I am using (as above) is validating anything and everything with a digit.Its not checking for validity of special charachters . Can someone please point to where I am going wrong ?
Update : used this

```
^([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[\/\\#-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$
```

Doesnt work for strings like -1 ,/1 etc

Comment: Will you consider using separate regex for each requirement, instead of having a super-regex that will check for all? I am not saying one regex is impossible, but it become unmaintainable if it looks too complicated.

Comment: When you said "It's not checking for validity of special characters", do you mean there must be at least one special character?

Comment: No special charachters are optional .By special charachters I mean only " \ / # - " . the above regex validates if there is '$' or some other special chars :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest regex I can think of is:

```
^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d\\/#-]{1,29}$
```

The character class and repetition is pretty straightforward. After adding `^` and `$` at the ends, the main Kung Fu is the anchored look ahead to assert the presence of a digit.

Answer (score 1):

It's matching anything with a digit because there is no anchor and all the other sub-expressions are optional. You need to begin your regex with `\A` or `^` and end it with `\Z` or `$` if you intend to match the entire string.